# When i click on the Delete, nothing happen also the same problem with the Delete Selected Tasks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i click on the Delete, nothing happen also the same problem with the Delete Selected Tasks

```
    import "./App.css";

    import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
```

state for tasks and state for deleting

```
    const App = () => {        
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: "Buy milk", completed: false },
    { id: 2, text: "Wash the dishes", completed: false },
    { id: 3, text: "Take out the trash", completed: false }
]);

const textInputRef = useRef();
const [tasksToDelete, setTasksToDelete] = useState([]); // Зміна тут

const addTodo = () => {
    const text = textInputRef.current.value;
    if (text.trim() !== "") {
        const newTodo = { id: Date.now(), text, completed: false };
        setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
        textInputRef.current.value = "";
    }
 };

 const toggleTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos(
        todos.map((todo) =>
            todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } 
 : todo
        )
    );
 };
```

Delete one tasks

```
 const toggleTaskToDelete = (taskId) => {
    if (tasksToDelete.includes(taskId)) {
        setTasksToDelete(tasksToDelete.filter((id) => id !== 
 taskId));
    } else {
        setTasksToDelete([...tasksToDelete, taskId]);
    }
 };
```

Deleted all selected tasks

```
 const deleteSelectedTasks = () => {
    const updatedTodos = todos.filter((todo) => 
 !tasksToDelete.includes(todo.id));
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
    setTasksToDelete([]); // Очищаємо всі вибрані таски
 };


 return (
    <div>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a todo..." ref= 
 {textInputRef} />
        <button onClick={addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
        <button onClick={deleteSelectedTasks}>Delete Selected 
 Tasks</button>
        <ul>
            {todos.map((todo) => (
                <TodoItem
                    key={todo.id}
                    text={todo.text}
                    completed={todo.completed}
                    onToggle={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
                    onDeleteToggle={() => 
 toggleTaskToDelete(todo.id)}
                    tasksToDelete={tasksToDelete}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
 );
 };
```

Component for listing tasks

```
 const TodoItem = ({ text, completed, onToggle, onDeleteToggle, 
 tasksToDelete }) => {
 return (
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} onChange= 
 {onToggle} />
        {text}
        <button onClick={onDeleteToggle}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  );
  };

  export default App;
```

I tried to use any methods, tried delete with id, without id, tried with includes and filter, but nothing works